I am getting a console.log error in my django react application with CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
According to the docs I have everything set up correctly but I am still getting an error.
This is the error message from :

console.log() Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/wells'
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is the code from settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'wells',
    'core',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

According to the docs, this should work. So, I am not sure how to fix the error.

You can try moving the 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', up the list (as the first entry). Also, what endpoint does the frontend try to access? Does it hit the localhost:3000 or does it try to access some other URL?

I moved it as suggested and get the same error. I have react on http://localhost:3000 and django on http://127.0.0.1:8000

I even added to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000', "http://127.0.0.1:3000"]

This is in my vite.config.js file   server: {
port: 3000
} So I think my front end is hitting localhost:3000

The problem was solved by clearing browser cache and reloading the page.
